# How map many-to-many don't use primary ID on FluentNhibernate

Tags: .net, orm, fluent-nhibernate

help me please.

I have 3 entities.

1. Family (GENERIC_ID,...)
2. BPayReference(BPayReferenceID,GENERIC_ID) where BPayReferenceID GeneratedBy.Assigned()
3. Invoice (ID, ..., BPayReferenceID) where BPayReferenceID foreign key to BPayReference.BPayReferenceID

How I can map many-to-many in this scenario?

I try in **FamilyMap**

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Invoices)
    .Table("bpay_reference")
    .ChildKeyColumn("GENERIC_ID")
    .ParentKeyColumn("BPayReferenceID");
```

but this does not work because `BPayReferenceID` is not the primary key in the `Invoice` entity

Answer (score 1):

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Invoices)
    .Table("bpay_reference")
    .ParentKeyColumn("GENERIC_ID")
    .ChildKeyColumn("BPayReferenceID")
    .ChildPropertyRef("BPayReferenceID"); // must be mapped though
```

note: you probably switched the KeyColumns

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone who - like me - struggled to do the same thing in unFluent NHibernate, try something like this:

```
<bag name="Invoices" table="BPayReference" cascade="none" lazy="false">
  <key column="GENERIC_ID" />
  <many-to-many class="Invoice" column="BPayReferenceID" property-ref="BPayReferenceID" />
</bag>
```

The important thing I missed was property-ref.